# How do you join across 3 tables while restricting one attribute to a specific value?

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry for the bad title but I'm not sure how to word this. Basically I have 4 tables:

- CheckedOutItems
- Book
- Game
- Movie

CheckedOutItems is a link table that just contains an itemID and a customerID. The other 3 tables have itemID + a bunch of info about them. I want to get the info about all the items that correspond to a user. For example, user '123' has a book and a movie in check out, I want to get the item info of that book and movie.

I thought it would be something like this but it isn't working:

```
SELECT * 
FROM CheckedOutItems
JOIN Book ON CheckedOutItems.itemID = Book.itemID
JOIN Game ON CheckedOutItems.itemID = Game.itemID
JOIN Movie ON CheckedOutItems.itemID = Movie.itemID
WHERE CheckedOutItems.customerID = 123
```

Comment: Try LEFT JOIN, and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variant 1 (fixing OP's code, but I think it is bad variant, especially due to JOIN multiplying):

```
SELECT * 
FROM CheckedOutItems
LEFT JOIN Book ON CheckedOutItems.itemID=Book.itemID 
LEFT JOIN Game ON CheckedOutItems.itemID=Game.itemID 
LEFT JOIN Movie ON CheckedOutItems.itemID=Movie.itemID
WHERE CheckedOutItems.customerID = 123
```

Variant 2 (needs the items tables structures to be the same - or they must be synced by adding matching empty fields):

```
    SELECT *, 'Book' item_type
    FROM CheckedOutItems
    JOIN Book ON CheckedOutItems.itemID=Book.itemID 
    WHERE CheckedOutItems.customerID = 123
UNION ALL
    SELECT *, 'Game' item_type
    FROM CheckedOutItems
    JOIN Game ON CheckedOutItems.itemID=Game.itemID 
    WHERE CheckedOutItems.customerID = 123
UNION ALL
    SELECT *, 'Movie' item_type
    FROM CheckedOutItems
    JOIN Movie ON CheckedOutItems.itemID=Movie.itemID
    WHERE CheckedOutItems.customerID = 123
```

Comment: thanks, this is what I was looking for. One question - how exactly would I sync the tables by adding matching empty fields? Really all I need are the fields that they "share" (e.g have the same name, like 'title').

Comment: @Avalon In UNION all subqueries must have the same amount of columns with positionally matched datatypes. For example, if 1st table is `(title TEXT, pages INT)` and second is `(title TEXT, grade VARCHAR)` and third is `(title TEXT, length TIME)` then the query may be `SELECT title, pages, '' grade, CAST(NULL AS TIME) length .. UNION ALL SELECT title, NULL, grade, NULL .. UNION ALL SELECT title, NULL, '', length ..`. Pay attention-I use NULL somewhere and empty string somewhere, and in the first subquery NULL must be CASTed to proper datatype whereas empty string does not need in such casting.